# RhinoMock Stub Linq Where clause for DbContext

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, rhino-mocks, stubbing

I was trying to unit test my repository. I need to mock the Where Clause with some values.
I have tried the following

```
var parentClass = new ParentClass {id = 1};

var subClass = new SubClass
{
    id=2,
    ParentClassId = parentClass.id,
    ParentClass = parentClass
}

var subSubClass = new SubSubClass
{
    id =3,
    SubClassId = subClass.id,
    SubClass = subClass
}

var dbContext = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IDbContext>();
    var subClassContext = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IDbSet<SubClass>>();
var subSubClassContext = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IDbSet<SubSubClass>>();

subClassContext.Stub(x => x.GetEnumerator())
                .Return(null)
                .WhenCalled(c => c.ReturnValue = new List<SubClass> { subClass }.GetEnumerator());

subSubClassContext.Stub(x => x.GetEnumerator())
                .Return(null)
                .WhenCalled(c => c.ReturnValue = new List<SubSubClass> { subSubClass }.GetEnumerator());
```

I am testing the following code

```
var existingSubSubClasses = context.SubSubClass.Where(cba => cba.SubClass.ParentClassId == parentClassId).ToList();
```

I am getting ArgumentNullReferenceException

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The code in your two code fragments don't directly relate to each other. What is `context` in the second fragment? It is `dbContext` from above, or something different?

Answer (score -1):

You should also stub `context.SubSubClass` property -- seems like it returns `null` by default.

Comment: dosen't seems like an answer to my query.